# Spring boot admin ui not visible (404)

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I've set up spring boot admin server with ui. No error in logs and json endpoints show info of my sample client application pointing to this server.
But, html ui not visible, returning 404. version is 1.5.6.
Any help will be muxh appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the `@EnableAdminServer` to your Spring Boot Application?

```
@EnableAdminServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

`